# Calculating averages of elements in a sequence without iterating over it

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Write a class that takes in a step size (n) in its constructor. The only method in the class takes in an integer, adds it into a sequence of numbers, and returns the average of the last n values inserted into the sequence. **Do not iterate over the sequence to calculate the average.**

*And NO, this isn't homework*

Following is my way of doing it in C++:

1. Initialize two STL `queue<int>`, one of which has length `n` and is called `buffer`
2. User - input values are stored dynamically in the buffer. Once this `buffer` is full, add the user - input value to "sum" and subtract the `buffer.front()` value.
3. Push the first value from `buffer` into the second `queue<int>` named `values`
4. Pop the first value (`buffer.pop()`)
5. return the average by dividing `sum` by `n`

Following is the code I came up with:

```
#ifndef calcAverage_Window_h
#define calcAverage_Window_h

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Window{
private:
    int n, sum;
    queue<int> values, buffer, sums;

public:
    Window(int);
    float calcAverage(int);
};

#endif


#include "Window.h"

Window::Window(int m){
    n = m;
    buffer.push(1);
    buffer.push(2);
    buffer.push(3);
    sum = 6;
}

float Window::calcAverage(int val){
    buffer.push(val);
    values.push(buffer.front());
    sum = sum + val - buffer.front();
    buffer.pop();

    return float(sum)/n; //float(sum) required so that calcAverage doesn't return an int
}


#include "Window.h"

int main()
{
    Window w(3);
    cout<<w.calcAverage(4)<<endl;
    cout<<w.calcAverage(5)<<endl;
    cout<<w.calcAverage(6)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If we are not allowed to use STL either, I would implement a queue and use that for `buffer` and `values`. Does anyone have a better idea?
3. I cheated a bit by initializing the buffer in the `Window(n)` constructor. That is because: 1) I did not know how else I would go about it
   2) It maybe clear for the case when `n = 2`, but it is ambiguous for `n = 3`.
4. Where will this method / code fail?
5. I came to think of this way empirically. Is there an algorithmic way to look at this problem?

Comment: You could do a weighted average with just the running sum, number of elements, and the new element.

Comment: @Joe: Indeed.  But that's not the same as a true moving average.

Comment: Scale back.  This code does far more than it needs to, and is buggy.

Comment: @KuldeepShah: That's not sufficient!  Do you mean faster?  Less memory?  Less code?  Cleaner?  Something else?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:
"better" - that which occupies less memory (especially when n tends to be large)
"better" - that which keeps a check on boundary conditions

Comment: You want to use less memory, don't use C++.

Comment: @RandyHoward: Can you justify that?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "better" - that which makes programmers feel satisfied and content when they read it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Using something that *behind the scenes* iterate still valid? If so you can use [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: @talles, No, I cannot iterate over the sequence
It wouldn't have made me think this much if I could just iterate, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer a few of your questions:

---

> Where will this method / code fail?

Well, assuming the above code is bug-free, it will not necessarily work correctly if you decide to move to floating-point data.

Note that its overflow behaviour is also subtly different compared to a direct implementation of a moving average.

---

> Is there an algorithmic way to look at this problem?

Yes. With window size `L` the moving sums for time `n` and time `n-1` are as follows:

```
y[n]   = x[n] + x[n-1] + ... + x[n-L+1]
y[n-1] =        x[n-1] + ... + x[n-L+1] + x[n-L]
```

Subtract one equation from the other, you get:

```
y[n] - y[n-1] = x[n] - x[n-L]
```

Move `y[n-1]` to the other side of the equals sign, and you're done.